# AddressSanitizer error on a throwing C++20 coroutine

Tags: c++, c++20, clang++, c++-coroutine

I was playing with C++20 coroutine support and I found an addressing error that I can't explain nor fix. It happens on Xcode 12.5, shipping with Apple Clang 12.0.5, when enabling *Address Sanitizer* feature. Here is a minimum reproducible example:

```
#include <experimental/coroutine>

struct ReturnType
{
    struct promise_type
    {
        std::experimental::suspend_never initial_suspend() { return {}; }
        std::experimental::suspend_always final_suspend() noexcept { return {}; }
        ReturnType get_return_object() { return {}; }
        void unhandled_exception() { throw; }
        void return_void() {}
    };
};

ReturnType my_coroutine()
{
    throw 0;
    co_return;
}

int main() {

    try {
        my_coroutine();
    } catch (...) {
    
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The coroutine merely `throw`s a dummy `int` which is rethrown in `promise_type::unhandled_exception`. No local variables, no manual allocations, but still *Address Sanitizer* reports the following error:

```
=================================================================
==3204==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: heap-use-after-free on address 0x60600004bb18 at pc 0x000100001ea9 bp 0x7ffeefbff0f0 sp 0x7ffeefbff0e8
READ of size 8 at 0x60600004bb18 thread T0
    #0 0x100001ea8 in my_coroutine() main.cpp:15
    #1 0x1000024e3 in main main.cpp:24
    #2 0x7fff204ed620 in start+0x0 (libdyld.dylib:x86_64+0x15620)

0x60600004bb18 is located 24 bytes inside of 64-byte region [0x60600004bb00,0x60600004bb40)
freed by thread T0 here:
    #0 0x1001810bd in wrap__ZdlPv+0x7d (libclang_rt.asan_osx_dynamic.dylib:x86_64h+0x550bd)
    #1 0x100001e76 in my_coroutine() main.cpp:15
    #2 0x1000024e3 in main main.cpp:24
    #3 0x7fff204ed620 in start+0x0 (libdyld.dylib:x86_64+0x15620)

previously allocated by thread T0 here:
    #0 0x100180c9d in wrap__Znwm+0x7d (libclang_rt.asan_osx_dynamic.dylib:x86_64h+0x54c9d)
    #1 0x10000153d in my_coroutine() main.cpp:15
    #2 0x1000024e3 in main main.cpp:24
    #3 0x7fff204ed620 in start+0x0 (libdyld.dylib:x86_64+0x15620)

SUMMARY: AddressSanitizer: heap-use-after-free main.cpp:15 in my_coroutine()
Shadow bytes around the buggy address:
  0x1c0c00009710: 00 00 00 00 fa fa fa fa 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x1c0c00009720: fa fa fa fa 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 fa fa fa fa
  0x1c0c00009730: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 fa fa fa fa 00 00 00 00
  0x1c0c00009740: 00 00 00 00 fa fa fa fa 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x1c0c00009750: fa fa fa fa 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 fa fa fa fa
=>0x1c0c00009760: fd fd fd[fd]fd fd fd fd fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x1c0c00009770: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x1c0c00009780: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x1c0c00009790: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x1c0c000097a0: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x1c0c000097b0: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
Shadow byte legend (one shadow byte represents 8 application bytes):
  Addressable:           00
  Partially addressable: 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 
  Heap left redzone:       fa
  Freed heap region:       fd
  Stack left redzone:      f1
  Stack mid redzone:       f2
  Stack right redzone:     f3
  Stack after return:      f5
  Stack use after scope:   f8
  Global redzone:          f9
  Global init order:       f6
  Poisoned by user:        f7
  Container overflow:      fc
  Array cookie:            ac
  Intra object redzone:    bb
  ASan internal:           fe
  Left alloca redzone:     ca
  Right alloca redzone:    cb
  Shadow gap:              cc
```

What is going on? Maybe a problem with the experimental coroutine support of Apple Clang 12?

Comment: what happens if `unhandled_exception` swallows the exception and doesn't re-throw it? anyway, you never free the coroutine-promise as you return `suspend_always` from `final_suspend` but never call `coroutine_handle::destroy`, so I anyway think this is a false positive. TSAN/ASAN unfortunately are not very accurate when it comes to coroutines.

Comment: plus: what happens if you change `throw` to be `throw std::current_exception()`?

Comment: @DavidHaim Without rethrowing (empty `unhandled_exception`), there is no error reported. Throwing `std::exception`, or any other type, is the same. And yes, there is no `destroy` called in this MRE, but I really doubt it is the source of the problem.